# Splitting an array at commas

Tags: performance, ruby, csv

I was given a file of size 46KB full of names (around ~5000), in the format as shown below:

```
"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH"..."DARRELL","ALONSO"
```

I wonder if my code below is optimal in doing what I want, which is to translate this txt file into an array of names.

```
array = []
File.readlines('names.txt').each do |l|
  array << l.delete("\"").split(",")
end

array.flatten
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, it takes 0.372798 seconds to run on my computer for a 50 MB file, for a 46KB file this runs in the blink of an eye.

Anyway as this is Codereview I suggest an equally fast but higher level version of your code:

```
def get_names(filename)
    File.read(filename).tr('"', '').split(',')
end
```

Comment: Thanks caridorc. Curious how you generate the 50MB file? :P

Comment: and yea, i think File.read is what I am looking for instead of using File.readlines, because there is just one line

Comment: @ChrisYeung Obvious, by hand, I had 8 hours to spare :P (not really, the code is `def rand_string(len)
    (0...len).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
end

def gen_file
    names = (1..10000).map{|x| '"'+rand_string(x)+'"'}.join(',')
    File.write("names.txt", names)
end
`

Comment: @200_success made a valid point where there may be names with commas within the quotes. how should we address that?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
def get_names(filename)
  File.read(filename).scan(/[a-z\s]+/i)
end
```

In this case, the `scan` looks for contiguous runs of letters and spaces, and captures those. So instead of removing quotes and splitting on commas, we're capturing stuff that *isn't* a comma or quote.

Don't know if it's faster, though (haven't tried it). Just presenting an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

My first concern is correctness, not speed.  The input string is quoted for a reason, presumably to allow for the possibility of a literal comma within one of the names, e.g. `"MARY, QUEEN OF SCOTS"`.  Granted, it would be weird for that situation to actually happen, but I think it's poor practice to disregard the quotes completely.

Therefore, I would go with @Snowbody's approach.  I would refine it a bit by stripping the double-quotes from just the first and last items of each line, based on the reasoning that modifying short strings should be faster than copying the entire line.

```
File.readlines('names.txt').flat_map do |line|
  line_names = line.split('","')
  line_names[0].delete!('"')
  line_names[-1].chomp!(',')
  line_names[-1].chomp!('"')
  line_names
end
```

Comment: That's definitely better, good job. Do string operations on the short string not the long one.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be faster:

```
def get_names(filename)
    ('",' + File.read(filename) + ',"').split('","')
end
```

due to the initial insert possibly reallocating.

Comment: It seems a bit hacky but i got your point.